# Categories and SubCategories

Tags: php, mysql

I've asked a question few hours ago - afterwards decided to change my sql structure.

I have 2 tables:

```
categories (id,title,parent_id)
articles (id,title,content,parent_id)
```

each article can have only 1 category, 

each category can have 1 parent category

an example:

```
article (id = 1) has : parent_id = 3
category (id = 3,'root') has: parent_id = 2
category (id = 2,'sub') has: parent_id = 1
category (id = 1,'subsub') has: parent_id = 0
```

I want to generate breadcrumbs for - `article (id=1)`

That would be shown as: `Root->sub->subsub`

What is the efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Categories and SubCategories.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132880/categories-and-subcategories)

Comment: Possible duplicate? It's the exact same thing posted by the same person. ;)

Comment: @domsterr yeah :) That's just the standard message posted by the system when you select a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When loading article, read all categories recursively and display breadcrumbs.
2. If you need get all parents more than one time per script (e.g. when you are loading 50 articles and need parents for each), use the *nested set model*, as explained in [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

you can create function and then call your function in function!

for example

```
function find(id){
   list_site = array();
   if whatsparent(id){
       list_site[] = whatsparent(id)["name"];
       find(whatsparent(id)["id"]);
   }
}

function whatsparent(x){
   ...
   return parent #array of parent detail
}
```

sorry if i have wrong in php... i'm python developer :D