# database structure for category and sub category

Tags: php, sql-server, recursion

I am bit confusion What can be best solution for category database structure. Here, I have the following cateogry list.

1. News

   1.1 General News

   1.2 Entertaintment News

   1.3 Sports News
2. Horoscope

   2.1 Daily Horoscope

   ```
     2.1.1 Aries

     2.1.2 Taurus

     2.1.3 Gemini

      .....

     2.1.12 Pisces
   ```

   2.2 Weekly Horoscope

   ```
     2.2.1 Aries

     2.2.2 Taurus

     2.2.3 Gemini

      .....

     2.2.12 Pisces
   ```
3. Jokes

This is my present category list. Here, I have to built admin panel where category and sub category can be added. Currently, I have 2 sub-category of Horoscope. In future more sub-category can be added like monthly and yearly Horoscope just for example. Another confusion is that daily and weekly horoscope have same sub-category that means single sub-category have multiple parent category. Here,How can I eliminate the duplication in database table. and I need to display category in tree structure using recursive function.
   I google for the solution, I couldn't find the appropriate answer. Would you plz provide me answer or links relataed to this. I am coding in php and MS-server database.

Comment: to my mind the best solution is to have a field `parent_id` which references to the same table

Comment: What sql-server version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132875/categories-and-subcategories ( There is general solution in my answer )

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like this, have a category table which has the following fields, id, parent_id and title,
each category then has either a parent_id or 0 for a top level category.

If you'd like you can have the titles be a different table holding id and title, and then you could refer on your category table to the appropriate title on the titles table.

Think of it, it will follow this rule set which is exactly what you're looking for:

- Each Category is associated with zero or more Category.
- Each Category is associated with one Title.
- Each Title is associated with one or more Category.

as for recursively representing it, it's fairly easy this way.
hope that'll do the trick for you.

Comment: would you please provide recursive function sample for looping through all category and sub category list..

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about recursive queries in sql 2005 using common table expressions.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/recursivequeriesinsql1999andsqlserver2005/1846/

I recommend you register for their newsletter, new stuff almost daily that might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

here is some ugly code I wrote few years ago... but it may help you as how-to

DB table "table_name" structure

```
ID  PARENT  NAME
1     0      1
2     0      2
3     1      1.1
4     1      1.2
5     4      1.2.1
6     4      1.2.2
7     2      2.1
```

getting and preparing data

```
$Select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Select)){
  if($Row['parent'] == 0){
    $Arr[$Row['id']] = $Row['name'];
  }else{
    $Childs[$Row['parent']][$Row['id']] = $Row['name'];
  }
}
```

some silly but sufficient function

```
function gettree($Array){
  global $Childs;
  foreach($Array as $key => $value){
    echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
    if(isset($Childs[$key])){
      echo '<li><ul>';
      gettree($Childs[$key]);
      echo '</ul></li>';
    }
  }
}
```

and bulding tree to html

```
echo '<ul>';
gettree($Arr);
echo '</ul>';
```

and result should by like this

```
1
 1.1
 1.2
  1.2.1
  1.2.2
2
 2.1
```

i recommend you rewrite it to your object for better use

> sorry for my english

Comment: I think there can be more than one array with same index. Here, array could have more than one same index since parent column haven't unique value e.g in while loop it may have $childs[1][1] two times that replaces previous value.

Comment: but ID column is unique so it will not replace previous value, just add another value to array. this solution uses multidimensional array.

Comment: oh.. my fault, I evidently did not get your answer. sorry

Answer (score 0):

your database structure should b this which contains their parent relevant ids and in admin panel fetch parent categories and sub parent categories in selectbox

```
USE `database`;


CREATE TABLE `category` (
`c_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` enum('active','inactive') DEFAULT 'active',
 PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `category` */

insert  into `category`(`c_id`,`category_name`,`status`) values (1,'For Sale','active'),(2,'Community','active'),(3,'Classes','active'),(4,'Vehicles','active'),(5,'Real Estate','active'),(6,'Services','active'),(7,'Matrimonial','active'),(8,'Jobs','active');
CREATE TABLE `sub_category` (
`sub_cat_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`c_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`sub_category_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` enum('active','inactive') DEFAULT 'active',
PRIMARY KEY (`sub_cat_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `sub_category` */

insert  into `sub_category`(`sub_cat_id`,`c_id`,`sub_category_name`,`status`) values (1,1,'Animals','active'),(2,1,'Art - Collectibles','active'),(3,1,'Books - Magazines','active'),(4,1,'Business - Industrial','active'),(5,4,'Cars','active'),(6,4,'Truck','active');
/*Table structure for table `sub_category_child` */
CREATE TABLE `sub_category_child` (
`sub_category_child_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`c_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sub_cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`sub_category_child_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`nature` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` enum('active','inactive') DEFAULT 'active',
 PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `sub_category_child`(`sub_category_child_id`,`c_id`,`sub_cat_id`,`sub_category_child_label`,`nature`,`status`) values (1,4,5,'Make','parent','active'),(2,4,5,'Model','child','active'),(3,4,5,'doors','independent','active'),(4,4,5,'accessories','independent','active'),(5,1,1,'abc','parent','active'),(6,4,6,'No of Tyre','parent','active'),(8,4,6,'loader','independent','active');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Cat_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Cat_Nm] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Parent_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_Category]    Script Date: 04/25/2012 07:30:14 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Category] ON [dbo].[Category] 
(
[Cat_Id] ASC,
[Cat_Nm] ASC,
[Parent_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Category]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Category] FOREIGN KEY([Parent_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Category] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Category]

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Category] ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Category]([id], [Cat_Id], [Cat_Nm], [Parent_Id])
SELECT 9, 1, N'Aries', 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 1, N'Aries', 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 1, N'Daily', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, N'General News', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, N'News', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, N'Enterntainment News', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, N'Horoscope', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 2, N'Taurus', 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 2, N'Taurus', 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 2, N'Weekly', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 3, N'Gemini', 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 3, N'Gemini', 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, N'Jokes', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3, N'Sports News', 1
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Category] OFF;

GO

CREATE VIEW Categories
AS
    WITH    cte ( id, Cat_Id, [Name], [Level] )
              AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        Cat_Id ,
                        Cat_Nm ,
                        CAST(Cat_Id AS VARCHAR(5))
               FROM     dbo.Category c
               WHERE    Parent_Id IS NULL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   c.id ,
                        c.Cat_Id ,
                        c.Cat_Nm ,
                        CAST(ct.[Level] + '.'
                        + CAST(c.Cat_Id AS VARCHAR(5)) AS VARCHAR(5))
               FROM     dbo.Category c
                        JOIN cte ct ON c.Parent_Id = ct.id
               WHERE    c.Parent_Id IS NOT NULL
             )
SELECT  Level ,
        Name
FROM    cte
```